# Redux Performance with Selectors

Tags: performance, redux, reselect

According to the Redux docs on performance, it states *"connected list components should pass item IDs to their connected child list items (allowing the list items to look up their own data by ID)"*.

This makes sense to me. In this fashion the child items `connect` to the Redux store and find the item using the itemId that was passed in via props.

Since this involves a small computation however, it is unclear to me if a reselect `selector` should be used for memoization. I suppose the root of the confusion comes from connect and how state tree changes cause recomputations.